# What is the format of "{123, affdsf, 223, 22, dgbwa, 33333}"?

Tags: r, format

I have the following format, please advise how to convert it to a list in R?

```
"{1948, 2507, 2510, 7030, 7110, 9009, 00027, 00206, 00399, 00717, 00814, 00828, 00848, 00917, 01050, 01105, 01144, 02130, 02768, 03037, 03752, 03754, 04070, 04110, 05050, 05255, 05289, 05564, 05595, 06100, 06330, 06671, 07041, 07119, 07137, 07273, 07313, 07454, 07871, 08104, 08714, 08726, 08995, 09059, 09073, 09525, 09949, 09981, 10092, 10439, 10782, 11185, 11507, 11712, 11806, 11858, 11980, 12067, 12113, 12139, 12643, 13820, 14534, 15007, 15014, 15549, 15953, 16151, 16174, 16634, 16733, 16888, 17111, 17207, 17377, 17721, 17900, 18118, 18400, 18686, 18880, 19080, 19342, 19444, 19772, 19790, 19891, 20091, 20245, 20402, 20811, 21114, 21345, 21811, 21881, 22222, 22311, 22320, 22831, 22969, 23251, 23572, 23734, 23862, 23889, 24034, 24463, 25172, 25688, 26143, 26221, 26803, 26850, 26898, 27497, 28291, 28343, 29411, 29419, 30024, 30561, 30923, 31345, 31351, 31555, 31927, 32198, 32861, 33020, 33040, 33095, 33188, 33311, 33368, 33377, 33475, 33519, 33574, 33592, 34207, 34235, 34272, 34484, 34854, 34872, 34875, 34876, 34880, 35222, 35292, 35344, 36177, 36266, 37038, 37060, 37548, 37686, 37700, 38139, 39368, 39369, 39633, 40132, 40698, 40704, 40744, 40819, 41311, 41971, 42102, 42616, 43055, 43211, 43234, 43428, 43494, 43934, 44117, 44252, 44272, 44301, 44336, 44619, 44866, 44888, 45049, 45197, 45412, 45718, 46694, 46736, 47000, 48046, 48540, 49078, 49109, 49216, 49388, 49464, 50056, 50155, 50217, 50477, 50692, 51122, 51445, 51946, 52475, 52537, 52982, 54011, 54031, 54160, 54963, 55000, 55537, 56080, 56163, 56282, 56760, 56787, 57102, 57727, 57871, 58101, 58558, 58882, 59902, 60225, 60397, 60501, 60619, 60703, 60890, 61075, 61894, 61944, 62322, 62337, 62380, 62413, 62729, 62766, 62923, 63010, 63234, 63977, 64127, 65359, 65428, 65542, 65750, 65863, 66184, 66636, 66712, 67201, 67439, 67953, 68133, 68854, 69251, 69959, 70107, 70725, 70768, 71081, 71099, 71948, 72013, 72377, 72400, 72420, 72735, 73000, 73015, 73142, 73223, 73455, 73717, 74049, 74492, 74854, 74941, 75142, 75399, 75464, 75587, 75618, 75642, 75887, 76357, 76651, 77199, 77302, 77456, 77579, 77601, 77649, 77668, 77694, 77745, 78006, 78010, 78178, 78335, 78656, 78729, 78808, 78824, 78844, 78945, 79416, 79471, 79915, 80077, 80111, 80189, 80262, 80409, 80470, 80529, 80539, 80838, 81272, 81513, 81658, 81740, 81743, 81762, 81843, 82001, 82070, 82106, 82342, 82472, 82719, 83670, 84009, 84151, 84299, 84430, 84450, 84460, 84945, 86411, 86443, 86446, 86668, 86942, 87286, 87317, 87624, 87785, 88023, 88517, 88696, 88787, 88868, 88977, 89206, 90108, 90440, 90734, 90802, 90849, 90920, 90931, 91011, 91031, 91133, 91777, 91949, 92162, 92494, 93012, 93172, 94300, 94517, 95142, 95410, 95559, 95859, 96112, 97255, 97787, 97986, 98240, 98817, 99050, 99198, 99222, 99241, 99295, 99326, 99335, 99503, 99603, 99643, 99803, 99968}"
```

THIS IS NOT A DUPLICATE OF [convert json to list in a vectorized way in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36658084/convert-json-to-list-in-a-vectorized-way-in-r)

IT'S COMPLETELY DIFFERENT BECAUSE THE FORMAT IS ABSOLUTELY DIFFERENT.

Comment: Is this json format? See here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2061897/parse-json-with-r

Comment: Possible duplicate of [convert json to list in a vectorized way in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36658084/convert-json-to-list-in-a-vectorized-way-in-r)

Comment: I recommend to change the title to something more clear and bound to the question.

Comment: @FlorinGhita please suggest.

Comment: @steves For example: How to convert a csv like format to an array/vector in R

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this one line code:

```
as.numeric(sapply(strsplit(substr(j,2,nchar(j)-1),split = ","),trimws))
  [1]  1948  2507  2510  7030  7110  9009    27   206   399   717   814   828   848   917  1050  1105  1144
 [18]  2130  2768  3037  3752  3754  4070  4110  5050  5255  5289  5564  5595  6100  6330  6671  7041  7119
 [35]  7137  7273  7313  7454  7871  8104  8714  8726  8995  9059  9073  9525  9949  9981 10092 10439 10782
 [52] 11185 11507 11712 11806 11858 11980 12067 12113 1213 ..
```

Your input:

```
j<-"{1948, 2507, 2510, 7030, 7110, 9009, 00027, 00206, 00399, 00717, 00814, 00828, 00848, 00917, 01050, 01105, 01144, 02130, 02768, 03037, 03752, 03754, 04070, 04110, 05050, 05255, 05289, 05564, 05595, 06100, 06330, 06671, 07041, 07119, 07137, 07273, 07313, 07454, 07871, 08104, 08714, 08726, 08995, 09059, 09073, 09525, 09949, 09981, 10092, 10439, 10782, 11185, 11507, 11712, 11806, 11858, 11980, 12067, 12113, 12139, 12643, 13820, 14534, 15007, 15014, 15549, 15953, 16151, 16174, 16634, 16733, 16888, 17111, 17207, 17377, 17721, 17900, 18118, 18400, 18686, 18880, 19080, 19342, 19444, 19772, 19790, 19891, 20091, 20245, 20402, 20811, 21114, 21345, 21811, 21881, 22222, 22311, 22320, 22831, 22969, 23251, 23572, 23734, 23862, 23889, 24034, 24463, 25172, 25688, 26143, 26221, 26803, 26850, 26898, 27497, 28291, 28343, 29411, 29419, 30024, 30561, 30923, 31345, 31351, 31555, 31927, 32198, 32861, 33020, 33040, 33095, 33188, 33311, 33368, 33377, 33475, 33519, 33574, 33592, 34207, 34235, 34272, 34484, 34854, 34872, 34875, 34876, 34880, 35222, 35292, 35344, 36177, 36266, 37038, 37060, 37548, 37686, 37700, 38139, 39368, 39369, 39633, 40132, 40698, 40704, 40744, 40819, 41311, 41971, 42102, 42616, 43055, 43211, 43234, 43428, 43494, 43934, 44117, 44252, 44272, 44301, 44336, 44619, 44866, 44888, 45049, 45197, 45412, 45718, 46694, 46736, 47000, 48046, 48540, 49078, 49109, 49216, 49388, 49464, 50056, 50155, 50217, 50477, 50692, 51122, 51445, 51946, 52475, 52537, 52982, 54011, 54031, 54160, 54963, 55000, 55537, 56080, 56163, 56282, 56760, 56787, 57102, 57727, 57871, 58101, 58558, 58882, 59902, 60225, 60397, 60501, 60619, 60703, 60890, 61075, 61894, 61944, 62322, 62337, 62380, 62413, 62729, 62766, 62923, 63010, 63234, 63977, 64127, 65359, 65428, 65542, 65750, 65863, 66184, 66636, 66712, 67201, 67439, 67953, 68133, 68854, 69251, 69959, 70107, 70725, 70768, 71081, 71099, 71948, 72013, 72377, 72400, 72420, 72735, 73000, 73015, 73142, 73223, 73455, 73717, 74049, 74492, 74854, 74941, 75142, 75399, 75464, 75587, 75618, 75642, 75887, 76357, 76651, 77199, 77302, 77456, 77579, 77601, 77649, 77668, 77694, 77745, 78006, 78010, 78178, 78335, 78656, 78729, 78808, 78824, 78844, 78945, 79416, 79471, 79915, 80077, 80111, 80189, 80262, 80409, 80470, 80529, 80539, 80838, 81272, 81513, 81658, 81740, 81743, 81762, 81843, 82001, 82070, 82106, 82342, 82472, 82719, 83670, 84009, 84151, 84299, 84430, 84450, 84460, 84945, 86411, 86443, 86446, 86668, 86942, 87286, 87317, 87624, 87785, 88023, 88517, 88696, 88787, 88868, 88977, 89206, 90108, 90440, 90734, 90802, 90849, 90920, 90931, 91011, 91031, 91133, 91777, 91949, 92162, 92494, 93012, 93172, 94300, 94517, 95142, 95410, 95559, 95859, 96112, 97255, 97787, 97986, 98240, 98817, 99050, 99198, 99222, 99241, 99295, 99326, 99335, 99503, 99603, 99643, 99803, 99968}"
```

This code removes first and last character of the string ("{" and "}" characters), splits values by "," and removes whitespaces using `trimws`. After that it moves the format to number.

Answer (score 1):

If it happens your data actually *is* json, stick with the `rjson` package. This answer is assuming your data *is not* json (since `rjson::fromjson` throws an error on your data)

Try:

```
string <- "{1948, 2507, 2510, 7030, 7110, 9009, 00027, 00206, 00399, 00717, 00814, 00828, 00848, 00917, 01050, 01105, 01144, 02130, 02768, 03037, 03752, 03754, 04070, 04110, 05050, 05255, 05289, 05564, 05595, 06100, 06330, 06671, 07041, 07119, 07137, 07273, 07313, 07454, 07871, 08104, 08714, 08726, 08995, 09059, 09073, 09525, 09949, 09981, 10092, 10439, 10782, 11185, 11507, 11712, 11806, 11858, 11980, 12067, 12113, 12139, 12643, 13820, 14534, 15007, 15014, 15549, 15953, 16151, 16174, 16634, 16733, 16888, 17111, 17207, 17377, 17721, 17900, 18118, 18400, 18686, 18880, 19080, 19342, 19444, 19772, 19790, 19891, 20091, 20245, 20402, 20811, 21114, 21345, 21811, 21881, 22222, 22311, 22320, 22831, 22969, 23251, 23572, 23734, 23862, 23889, 24034, 24463, 25172, 25688, 26143, 26221, 26803, 26850, 26898, 27497, 28291, 28343, 29411, 29419, 30024, 30561, 30923, 31345, 31351, 31555, 31927, 32198, 32861, 33020, 33040, 33095, 33188, 33311, 33368, 33377, 33475, 33519, 33574, 33592, 34207, 34235, 34272, 34484, 34854, 34872, 34875, 34876, 34880, 35222, 35292, 35344, 36177, 36266, 37038, 37060, 37548, 37686, 37700, 38139, 39368, 39369, 39633, 40132, 40698, 40704, 40744, 40819, 41311, 41971, 42102, 42616, 43055, 43211, 43234, 43428, 43494, 43934, 44117, 44252, 44272, 44301, 44336, 44619, 44866, 44888, 45049, 45197, 45412, 45718, 46694, 46736, 47000, 48046, 48540, 49078, 49109, 49216, 49388, 49464, 50056, 50155, 50217, 50477, 50692, 51122, 51445, 51946, 52475, 52537, 52982, 54011, 54031, 54160, 54963, 55000, 55537, 56080, 56163, 56282, 56760, 56787, 57102, 57727, 57871, 58101, 58558, 58882, 59902, 60225, 60397, 60501, 60619, 60703, 60890, 61075, 61894, 61944, 62322, 62337, 62380, 62413, 62729, 62766, 62923, 63010, 63234, 63977, 64127, 65359, 65428, 65542, 65750, 65863, 66184, 66636, 66712, 67201, 67439, 67953, 68133, 68854, 69251, 69959, 70107, 70725, 70768, 71081, 71099, 71948, 72013, 72377, 72400, 72420, 72735, 73000, 73015, 73142, 73223, 73455, 73717, 74049, 74492, 74854, 74941, 75142, 75399, 75464, 75587, 75618, 75642, 75887, 76357, 76651, 77199, 77302, 77456, 77579, 77601, 77649, 77668, 77694, 77745, 78006, 78010, 78178, 78335, 78656, 78729, 78808, 78824, 78844, 78945, 79416, 79471, 79915, 80077, 80111, 80189, 80262, 80409, 80470, 80529, 80539, 80838, 81272, 81513, 81658, 81740, 81743, 81762, 81843, 82001, 82070, 82106, 82342, 82472, 82719, 83670, 84009, 84151, 84299, 84430, 84450, 84460, 84945, 86411, 86443, 86446, 86668, 86942, 87286, 87317, 87624, 87785, 88023, 88517, 88696, 88787, 88868, 88977, 89206, 90108, 90440, 90734, 90802, 90849, 90920, 90931, 91011, 91031, 91133, 91777, 91949, 92162, 92494, 93012, 93172, 94300, 94517, 95142, 95410, 95559, 95859, 96112, 97255, 97787, 97986, 98240, 98817, 99050, 99198, 99222, 99241, 99295, 99326, 99335, 99503, 99603, 99643, 99803, 99968}"
```

string as list of `characters`:

```
string_as_list_char <- as.list(strsplit(gsub('\\{|\\}', '', string), ", "))[[1]]
```

or converted to `numeric`:

```
string_as_list_num <- as.list(as.numeric(strsplit(gsub('\\{|\\}', '', string), ", ")[[1]]))
```

Comment: Thanks for the great solution